# Starman and MovableType 5.2

Tags: perl, amazon-ec2, movabletype, psgi, starman

MovableType 5.2 has builtin PSGI support (via a mt.psgi in the main directory) and I've been trying to take advantage of it using starman/plackup.

Starman w/ MT fires up, but I get odd Not Founds and a silent hang & fail when I run mt-upgrade.cgi.

How I am running starman:

```
cd /home/ec2-user/mysite/perl/components/movabletype
plackup -s Starman --port 8045 --error-log /home/ec2-user/mysite/perl/logs/starman.log --pid /home/ec2-user/mysite/perl/var/starman.pid -a mt.psgi
```

Mystery 1: My browser returns "Not Found" for index.html, but mt-static and mt.cgi is reachable.

```
X http://mysite:8045/mt/index.html ... Not Found 
✓ http://mysite:8045/mt-static ... listing of static assets 
✓ http://mysite:8045/mt/mt.cgi ... redirects to ... 
X http://mysite:8045/mt/mt-upgrade.cgi?__mode=install ... fails
```

Mystery 2: Due to the redirect I believe that MT code is running. But it is mostly silent in the starman log even though I have tried different MT debug options. Worse, the mt-upgrade.cgi seems to be reached then fails with this lone message to the starman log:

```
[mypid] Bootstrap CGI script in non-buffering mode: /home/ec2-user/mysite/perl/components/movabletype/mt-upgrade.cgi
```

This non-buffering message seems informational and normal, and is coming from the MT codebase.

I have also run directly under starman and get the same result.

Any ideas or help would be appreciated!

System/Environment:

```
MT_HOME='/home/ec2-user/mysite/perl/components/movabletype'

linux AMI on an amazon ec2.

perl-5.16.0 under perlbrew.
```

CPAN modules:

```
cpanm starman
cpanm CGI::PSGI
cpanm CGI::Parse::PSGI
cpanm CGI::Compile
yum install expat-devel
cpanm XML::Parser
cpanm SOAP::Lite
cpanm SOAP::Transport::HTTP
cpanm XMLRPC::Transport::HTTP::Plack
cpanm DBI
sudo yum install postgresql9-devel
cpanm DBD::Pg
cpanm Task::Plack
```

MT config:

```
CGIPath    http://mysite:8045/mt

StaticWebPath    http://mysite:8045/mt-static

PIDFilePath /home/ec2-user/mysite/perl/var/starman.pid

DebugMode 1

ObjectDriver DBI::postgres
Database db
DBUser dbuser
DBPassword dbpass
DBHost dbhost.mysite
```

Comment: I don't know if the `StaticFilePath` config directive is important for this, but I know it is for some things.

Answer (score 2):

I'm Yuji Takayama, lead engineer of Movable Type. I did try to reproduce your steps but I was not able to reproduce this. (this means I got initial install screen)

So, Can you try with mysql? also can you try "tools/upgrade" script? I think you can get error messages when some errors occurs.

ex.)
cd MT_HOME; perl -Ilib -Iextlib tools/upgrade --username  --password  --nickname  --email  --preferred_language   --site_name  --site_url  --site_path  --site_theme  --site_timezone

And, I have answer about "index.html was not found".

Reason: MT will never mount MT_HOME as static files directory like a mt_static, because we think that MT_HOME must not be possible to list.

Comment: Thanks Yuji! I have since moved on to a custom solution but I do think that mysql is the best option for MT and WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to run Movable Type under Starman, I would seriously recommend running the upgrade script that comes with Movable Type using the command-line equivalent of your choice.  There is no good reason for mt-upgrade.cgi to become persistent in the manner that Starman and Plack permit.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your paths in mt-config.cgi to relative paths, not URLs. Like so:

```
CGIPath /mt/
StaticWebPath /mt-static/
```

Just curious: although it does work now, are you aware that PG isn't supported and that you're taking a risk that a future version of MT might break with it?

P.S. also don't forget the PIDFilePath directive mentioned in [the documentation](https://github.com/movabletype/Documentation/wiki/En-dev-bootstrap-mt-psgi).

Comment: I tried these 2 changes and they did not change the bad behaviors outlined in the question. I did forgot to show the PIDFilePath config, just added it to the question. I'm definitely thinking about the postgres risk, I need to use though as I want to use its queryable json datatype. If there is no clear solution soon, I'll try mysql out too to make sure.

Comment: Thanks for the response @francois-nonnenmacher... So I just tried it with a DBI::sqlite MT config. Result: same set of behaviors as postgres, but a sqlite db file was created with zero-length.

Comment: I remember having the same issue at first but then it worked (something about permission settings and cd'ing to the MT directory before running Plack, which you seem to do). I didn't perform an upgrade though, you might want to make a quick test starting with a fresh install just to see if that setting works (getting the upgrade script out of the equation).

Comment: After unzipping MT again and trying this out with both the postgres and the sqlite configs, it still failed but took several seconds longer in the hang. Then this message, 4 times, in the starman.log: [pid] Bootstrap CGI script in non-buffering mode... at least something new!

Answer (score 0):

BTW, a 404 on `http://mysite:8045/mt/index.html` looks quite normal. You're not supposed to have your site index at the same level than MT (you could, but that's not the recommended setup and it won't work in a stock MT install that assumes that MT and the produced sites are clearly separated).

Comment: Definitely agree about the separation of what is generated and mt itself. I thought it was odd to get the 404 because there is an index.html in the movabletype directory (this is an intro page to get new UI-based install started). But I have not dig into what is happening in terms of configuring psgi enough in the mt code base...